# Highcharts rendering cycle (numerous label formatter calls)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

*tl;dr included*

I have a `yAxis.labels.formatter` that

```
/**
 * Formats yAxis labels in order to include the min/max dates of the row
 *
 * /!\ Scared of performance issues
 * /!\ because the formatter is called 4 times on init,
                                       twice on resize, 
                                       and once on update
 * /!\ On top of that, the formatter is called once per category (label)
 * /!\ and my (poopy) function loops over all the data, each time
 * /!\ as a result, we have
 *          => 4 x nbOfCategories x nbOfData
 *  calls of this function :( --> see console logs
 */
```

As mentioned, on initial render, the formatter function is called 4 times, per category (and my current implementation already loops over all data each time, which is a very bad idea, I know, but this'll change: see "*real question*"). During the first two, calls, `this.chart.series[0].data` is still empty but if I try to skip that (by commenting the `line 79` of the [linked demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltk42e8h/3/)), then the chart instantiates without the proper label formatting (even though my function is still called twice). ***(This is already pretty weird, no ?)***

I'm suspecting HighCharts has some kind of life-cycle, order, for drawing/updating the chart causing this but don't know which.

#### Real Question

My ***real question*** would then be "How should I go about this (formatting axis labels) / is there a cheaper way to 'force' label updates manually ?"

I'm not exactly looking for an optimized function (but those are still welcomed) as I am already planning on computing these labels outside of HighCharts and pass them as `userOptions` so as to reduce the cost from `4 x nbOfCategories x nbOfData` to just `4 x nbOfCategories` but, ideally, I'd like a way to **reduce it to just `nbOfCategories`** (like how there is just one call when updating the series' data).

#### tl;dr:

Is there a way to reduce the number of label formatter calls (currently 4), on initial render, with HighCharts' "life-cycle" ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that attaching result of the **yAxisCatergoryMinMaxValueFormatter** function into the data point as an id and show it in formatter could be a better solution.

```
for (let i of data1){
    i.id =  "" + i.name + "<br><b>" + toDdMmDateFormat(new Date(i.start)) + " — " + toDdMmDateFormat(new Date(i.end)) + "</b>"
}
```

and

```
formatter(){
    let data = this.chart.series[0].userOptions.data;
    return data[this.pos].id
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4h3wqm2u/

Comment: This doesn't work if there are more than one task per line. I'm trying to display the "total" (`<min date> - <max date>`) of the whole row/line/category while having multiple tasks per line. In your demo, if you get multiple datas on the same category, only the first data's `id` is shown on the label, not the "total". I think I'll keep my solution (except I'll pre-process it for better performances). I also don't seem to find a way to simply update the yLabels afterwards without fully destroying the chart...

Comment: Yes, you're right. I modified the logic. Now it works when it is more than one task per line: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z07ares8/

Comment: (1/2) Ah yes, I think I'll do something similar (pre-processing these extremes and assigning somewhere). Unfortunately for me, my data doesn't always arrive in order and, on top of having multiple tasks per row, I'm also using the `parent` attribute to create groups (hierarchy) etc... But that's easy to manage. What I find most concerning is that the `yAxis` labels don't update when data does. You can try on your demo or on this one (drag drop then click the update/redraw button, you may see the xLabels update according to width but not the Ys)

Comment: (2/2) I was going to create another SO question about these two things:

Comment: (2/2) I was going to create another SO question about these two things:
- Drag Dropping a "child" task doesn't trigger the "parent" (`Dank`) to recompute its extremes
- Updating a data won't redraw/update the yAxis labels (even though the formatter is called, see console)

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4qo7ehsc/)

Comment: I think that it will be better, to avoid the mess, if a new question on SO will be opened.